# Session was already closed in ASP .NET Session Per Request pattern

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, ado.net

I'm using Session Per Request approach in ASP .NET Web Forms application.

This is the code that runs when request ends, and this is how I close session:

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ISession session = ManagedWebSessionContext.Unbind(HttpContext.Current, SessionFactoryProvider.SessionFactory);

        if (session != null)
        {
            if (session.Transaction != null && session.Transaction.IsActive)
            {
                session.Transaction.Rollback();
            }
            if (session.IsOpen)
            {
                session.Close();    
            }
        }
    }
```

Pretty obvious stuff. However I'm constantly getting exception when calling **session.Close**. The exception is of type **SessionException** and the message is:

> {"Session was already closed"}

The stack trace is:

```
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Close() in d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:line 343
```

The version of NHibernate I'm using is : **3.0.0.4000**

I've already searched for code that could close the session, but haven't found any. Also I've tested it with simple requests that do nothing with session object, and still the same. Any thoughts what could be the issue?

**EDIT: After divide and conquer session, I've targeted a piece of code that is responsible for that exception**:

```
                    var session = SessionFactoryProvider.GetCurrentSession();
                    using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        session.Update(instrument);
                        tx.Commit();
                    }
```

If I comment it out session is closed smoothly in EndRequest handler and no **Session was already closed** exception is thrown.

Comment: The ISession is IDisposable, so you should prefer to call Dispose() on it instead. That version of NH is really really old and it was also the first in the NH 3 series, so maybe you should try upgrading.

Comment: Thanks. I used Dispose and still the same. What I managed to spot, is that explicit transaction causes the issue. I'll update the question.

Comment: That is strange... Transactions should always be "explicit" for best compatibility, so there must be more to this story.

Comment: Might there be some error handler somewhere that would close the session?

Comment: I don't think so. I wrote that app from first line of code :)

Comment: Are you using TransactionScope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was resolved by moving to NHibernate 3.3.1.

However, other issue surfaced:

[Could not find the property - exception after switching from NHibernate 3 to 3.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192103/could-not-find-the-property-exception-after-switching-from-nhibernate-3-to-3-3)

Answer (score 1):

We are using `IHttpModule`, this way:

```
public class ModuleSessionNHibernate : IHttpModule
{
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BeginTransaction);
            context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(CommitAndCloseSession);
        }

        private void CommitAndCloseSession(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // commit or rollback depending on errors
            // then close session
        }

        ...
}
```

And in web.config

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="NHibernateSessionModule" type="XXX.ModuleSessionNHibernate, XXX"/>
</httpModules>
```

**EDIT:** About commit and close session (but we are using a lot of Helper and Services...)

```
    private void CommitAndCloseSession(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (no exception in context)
            {
                // commit transaction
            }
            else
            {
                // rollback transaction
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                // close session
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // send email                       
            }

                // rollback
                // close

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, but how BeginTransaction / CommitAndCloseSession looks like? Basically this is the part that is interesting. Whether you use Global .asax or IHttpModule is just a matter of approach and separation of concerns - and of course your approach is better :)

Comment: I updated my post but as we are using a lot of helper and stuffs, it might not be very helpful to you. I think that behind most of deals with methods of sessionNhibernate.