# Could not find the property - exception after switching from NHibernate 3 to 3.3.1

Tags: c#, .net, string, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class with a field:

```
    protected DateTime insertDate;
```

This is mapping for this fiels:

```
    <property name="InsertDate" access="field.camelcase" update="false" />
```

This field is set when with ctor

```
    public DocuBase(DateTime insertDate)
```

and is persisted only when row is added to the database. **I don't need property for it at all, no setter & no getter.** I worked in NHibernate 3.

And now, I've moved from NHiberbate 3 to NHibernate 3.3.1, and I get this exception when session factory is created:

> Could not find the property 'InsertDate', associated to the field
>   'insertDate', in class 'XXXX'

Why is is happening & how can I change mapping in order to get rid of the exception?

**EDIT:** Below answer is completly correct. But for those of you that don't need/don't want to have a property, and only field, there's another solution:

- set name attribute to field name (in my case it is **insertDate**) and remember to have correct column name

  ```
  <property name="insertDate" column="InsertDate" access="field.camelcase" update="false" />
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is **case** sensitivity, this will work.

```
<property name="insertDate" column="InsertDate" update="false" />
```

Looks like in release 3.1.0, there was a [breaking change](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2556)

*NH today accepts code below. It would be better if this would throw - it causes problem when configurate NH (or 3rd party tools) other ways than by hbm, using the property name (or memberinfo) of the public interface.*

```
[hbm]
<property name="Name" access="field.camelcase" />

[code]
string name;
public virtual string SomeThingCompletelyDifferent{
                                  get {return name;}
                                  set{name=value;}
}
```

**Note: This will be a breaking change.**

ps - updated answer to remove reference to use Property with private set as this was not what was being looked for and above breaking change is more relevant.

Comment: Well, I don't have a property. I don't need it. I only need a field - it's mentioned in the question.

Comment: okay, hear you, though can you switch to a property just to test that?  might isolate issue a bit.

Comment: Switching it into property works. But I don't like it :) Another solution that works is something similar to what you wrote, namely:         <property name="insertDate" column="InsertDate" access="field.camelcase" update="false" /> - and this is workaround that I'm using now. Yet, I'm curious why NHibernate 3.3.1 is looking for a property in the first place.

Comment: What's not to like?  Seriously though, what's the difference between the property I have and your field? Just because I can't think of an influencing reason doesn't mean there isn't.  Worked with NHibernate never used or seen fields much.  Not sure if performance is much of a factor: http://jaychapman.blogspot.ie/2007/11/nhibernate-access-performance.html  Could it be that they have deprecated some of their usage, will take a look at their release notes

Comment: @dragonfly found the breaking change, updating answer with it now

Comment: nice when there's a concrete reason for a fix rather than relying on it just working alright.  think this will prove a very good question some folk.

Comment: Thanks for research & thorough answer!